# "Result not set" error while using PCA from scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have Numpy array with the shape (774743, 135), and when I run `pca.fit()` with this data, I get `Result not set` error during the SVD process. What should I fix to remove this error? Here’s the code:

```
scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
data = scaler.fit_transform(df)
pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA()
pca.fit(data) #Error here
```

And the error:

```
~/anaconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daal/algorithms/svd.py in compute(self)
    613 
    614     def compute(self):
--> 615         return _svd.Batch_Float64DefaultDense_compute(self)
    616     __swig_destroy__ = _svd.delete_Batch_Float64DefaultDense
    617     __del__ = lambda self: None

SystemError: Result not set
```

Comment: What `svd_solver` do you use?

Comment: currently it's setup as 'auto'.

Comment: Should the input array shape be N by N?

Comment: No, if I run `data = scaler.fit_transform(np.random.rand(774743, 135))` it works ok for me with `full` and `randomized` sovlers.

Comment: It works when I do the fit_transform with the scaler, but I get the error when I do pca.fit()

Comment: Okay.. somehow the error got removed when I added `n_components` argument when initializing the PCA: `pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components = 50)`.